# Are SD flash memory cards "secure"?

Tags: security, sd-card

Regarding SD flash memory cards, SD stands for Secure Digital. Do SD cards or any of its variants (SDHC, SDXC) have any particular security features compared to other types of flash memory cards such as Compact Flash or Memory Stick?

Comment: No, there are no additional security features on these disks than on any other flash type of media. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_digital for details about the type of media.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Secure" in Secure Digital is a reference to their being developed in conjunction with a DRM standard called the Secure Digital Music Initiative.  One of the intended roles for them was as a replacement for CDs.

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Digital#History